# What is the file format for local directory, when setting up file sharing on lamp?

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I am currently using google cloud as a host server.  I have set up the Apache.  I get to the point on my linux ubuntu 14.04 where it has me set up my file sharing .  Note : My work station is a windows 7 based system.  The linux is the operating system of of the server being used to run lamp.

On google cloud the command is as follows :
gcloud compute copy-files [LOCAL_FILE_PATH] lamp-tutorial:/var/www/html

My problem is that I don't know what format the local file path is.  I have tried with the c drive and without.  I have tied multiple folders with in my c drive and each one comes with with same error.  "No such file or directory"

Any help on this matter would be appreciated.  This is my first time doing this.

Thanks;
Ben

Comment: "my linux ubuntu 14.04" and " the c drive"?? Linux doesn't do drive letters. Use a unix-style file path. Unless you mean the _server_ is running Ubuntu? It's not clear. Also https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/copy-files says the method is deprecated and you should be using https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp instead.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I am sorry I didn't make that more clear.  The linux is the operating system of the virtual computer created to run the lamp (server aspect  ) .  I have a windows 7 workstation that I am using google cloud to run the server aspect of things.  In this process I need to map or share the local file path on my computer to the server which is a linux based operating system.

Comment: Are you running this command from the VM, or from your Windows workstation? Also, according to https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files you could just use WinSCP to transfer files using a GUI, would that help?

Comment: Yes I am running the this command from the VM. that is on my windows workstation.  The vm I am using is through Google Cloud.  WinSCP makes alot of sense and does seem an easier route than this linux based VM I am using.  So, thanks for the help.

Comment: "Yes I am running the this command from the VM. that is on my windows workstation" eh? Isn't the VM in the google cloud? Isn't that the whole point? How can the VM be on your windows workstation? And..."does seem an easier route than this linux based VM I am using" Again what? WinSCP is a program which runs on your windows workstation. it's not alternative to your virtual machine (VM). Isn't the entire point of this to transfer files _from_ windows _to_ the VM which is in the google cloud? I don't quite follow your logic with those sentences. Are you confused about what is located where?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.  To clarify:  I have a windows 7 workstation.  (My home computer).  On it I am running the vm which is a virtual machine.  When I state "on it "  I mean it has pop up and it is on my computer.  The virtual machine is indeed running on the google cloud, which is kind of the point of calling it a vm.  This vm is running linux.    The vm is what I am using to run apache and mysql.   It does make sense, if I want to bypass the file transfer command on the cloud and use winscp to do the transfer instead.    I hope that puts things more into perspective.

Comment: I only asked because VMs can also be actually hosted by your workstation, and not hosted in the cloud, so that's where I was a little confused by your wording. Of course it pops up on your screen, (otherwise how would you see it!) but it doesn't mean it's actually contained within your workstation. It makes sense now. So yes you can install WinSCP on the Windows O/S and use it to transfer stuff to the cloud VM.